# how to connect ejs file to .js file?

Tags: node.js, visual-studio, express, ejs

[app.js image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xThOj.png)

i have two files app.js and landing.ejs and while running server ,it displays no error and the server is running but when i go to http://localhost:3000/ iam getting the name of the ejs file ,not the html content in the ejs file..please help me with this.

[browser image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LPROJ.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R8Le8.png)

Comment: Give your app.js file code in your question too.

Comment: Most likely you wrote res.send("landing"); instead of res.render("landing");

Answer (score 1):

Use this code in your app.js file. Set ejs view engine in app.js

```
   var express = require('express');
   var app = express();

   // set the view engine to ejs
    app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
    app.set("views", "views/")
```

Then use get request for your landing page in your app.js file

```
    app.get('/', function(req, res) {
       res.render('views/landing');
     });
```

Comment: If you fix this error from this code then accept it as answer.